# What data can be monitored of an HTTPS connection?

Tags: https, privacy

Suppose that my computer is not compromised. If somebody is listening somewhere between my computer and the server (my ISP for example), what can they see of my HTTPS connection?

1. I assume they can see the domain (e.g. google.com).
2. But what about the specific site I'm browsing (e.g. /wiki/Privacy in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Privacy)?
3. What about the subdomain (e.g. en in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Privacy)?
4. What about GET parameters, everything after the '?' (e.g. https://www.google.com/search?q=privacy). Can they see what I search on google?

Please feel free to add more info in case I've missed to ask something relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example: https://www.google.com/search?q=privacy

They can see

- The full domain (domain or subdomain, here "www.google.com")
- The ip of the contacted domain
- The approximate size of the exchanged data
- The duration of the exchange(s)

They cannot see:

- The path  (the part of the url after the domain, here "/search")*
- The GET or POST parameters (here "?q=privacy")
- The content of the answer
- The cookies

*After a bug in proxy discovery, the path and GET parameters may be transmitted in plain text (http://www.securitynewspaper.com/2016/08/01/proxy-pac-hack-allows-intercept-https-urls/).

And with the approximate size of the exchanged data, it may be possible to infer witch pages were visited.

Comment: "After a bug in proxy discovery..." what do you mean by that?

Comment: @user1785730 I've add the reference: http://www.securitynewspaper.com/2016/08/01/proxy-pac-hack-allows-intercept-https-urls/ , it's supposed a MitM and is probably not relevant in this case, but as your ISP have a box inside your network, it worth mentioning.